# NSArray error: initializer element is not constant

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I declared this array in my view controller implementation file:

```
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray array];
```

I wanted an empty, mutable array that I would later add UIImageViews to. It always return the error:

```
initializer element is not constant
```

Comment: Show how (where) you declared `images`. Most likely it is a global or static variable so you can't assign the value like you are.

Comment: Maybe the code is `static NSMutableArray* images= [NSMutableArray array]`?

Comment: im a noobie programmer. So one, this is the only place that images is declared, and two: should this be in the view controller class even?

Comment: @user1624992 But where exactly is this line of code? Show some context. Is this before the `@implementation` line? After? If after, is it inside curly braces or not?

Comment: ahh, I see the problem; Its not in a function, its just after the @implementation... line. I need to put it in a function or something. In that case, how would I make it available to other functions (global)?

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution is to make `images` an instance variable and then you initialize it in your `init` method.

```
@implementation SomeClass {
    NSMutableArray *images; // instance variable
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}
```

This is an example. If you have a specific `init...` method, use that instead.

As an instance variable, other methods in the class now have access to `images` and each instance of the class gets its own copy of `images`.

Comment: Do I need setters and getters for images?

Comment: "Need" - no. Though the general recommendation is to create a property. If `images` is only used within the class then create a private property declared in a class extension in the .m file. If other classes need access then you should add a public property in the .h file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show more code, but the problem is pretty obvious if that really is the line that is erroring out.

You can only **dynamically** initialization variables at the time of declaration in very specific spots.   **Dynamically** includes calling a method.

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array]; // this will error.
static NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array]; // this will error.
@implementation Booger
{
      NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array]; // this will error
}
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array]; // this will error.
- (void)bar
{
   NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array]; // this is fine
}
```

Sounds like you need to dive a bit more deeply on the whole object-oriented thing.   A class is a collection of functions called methods that either operate on the class (class methods) or a single instance of the class  (instance methods).   An instance can store state that is accessible to all methods when any method is invoked on that instance.   In traditional OO, such state is stored in *instance variables*.   Typically, you would define a pair instance methods that set and get that instance variable's value.  These are called accessors or setter/getter.   In modern Objective-C, we use *properties* to declare both the instance variables and the methods that access the instance variable.

Thus:

```
@interface MyClass:NSObject
@property(strong) NSMutableArray *myArray;
@end

@implementation MyClass
// the @property will automatically create an instance variable called _myArray,
// a getter method called -myArray and a setter called -setMyArray:

- init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
       _myArray = [NSMutableArray array]; // set the ivar directly in init
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)maybeAddThisThing:(Thing *)aThing
{
     if ([aThing isCool] && ![[self myArray] containsObject:aThing]) {
         [[self myArray] addObject:aThing];
     }
}

- (void)nukeFromOrbit
{
    [self setMyArray:[NSMutableArray array]];
    // or you could do [[self myArray] removeAllObjects];
}
```

Comment: ok, but then how would I make the array accessable in other functions if its only local to the one function (in this case bar)?

Comment: You use properties: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Comment: However, I am using Xcode 3.1.4. It will not recognize the property... as a decleration of an instance variable. Also, I tried using the @synthesize myArray, and I tried synthesize myArray=_myArray and it still did not work

Comment: @user1624992 Xcode 3.1.4?! Why? You do realize that your app won't be accepted by Apple using such an old version. You really should update to Xcode 4.6 and take advantage of MANY new features of both iOS and Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

The return of your `NSMutableArray` construction does not have an address known at compile time. You can only initialise dynamically inside method scope.

*Static* initialisation would be fine though: For example, `NSString *myString = @"Hello String";` in global scope will compile just fine.